# Mysql docker file is not running: Assertion failure: log0recv.cc:3561:err == DB_SUCCESS thread 139674864518912

Tags: mysql, docker

I have created a Docker file with a mysql instance. When running it:

```
docker run -d --name privacy-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=DockerPasswort! -e MYSQL_DATABASE=privacy-database -v C:\Users\Alexa\OneDrive\Backend_web_architecture\github_repos\data-privacy-api\db\db_records:/var/lib/mysql -v C:\Users\Alexa\OneDrive\Backend_web_architecture\github_repos\data-privacy-api\db\docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d --network privacy-network -dit -p 3306:3306 mysql:latest --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
docker exec -it privacy-mysql bash
This gives the server response:
Error response from daemon: Container 195ec7766070354801e1db751d76931fb6b2bb7db0ed85c124e776409d6630c7 is not running
```

When running `docker logs -f privacy-mysql` to see what is going on in the computer. This is the output:

```
2020-04-21 16:02:09+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian10 started.
2020-04-21 16:02:09+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-04-21 16:02:09+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian10 started.
2020-04-21T16:02:10.636147Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2020-04-21T16:02:10.636782Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19) starting as process 1
2020-04-21T16:02:10.645010Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2020-04-21T16:02:11.002713Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012671] [InnoDB] Encryption algorithm support missing: N
2020-04-21T16:02:11.002822Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: log0recv.cc:3561:err == DB_SUCCESS thread 139674864518912
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
16:02:10 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x55b0b5a7e9a0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7f0896aefce0 thread_stack 0x46000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x2e) [0x55b0b2fe596e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x323) [0x55b0b2424ee3]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12730) [0x7f08a8d84730]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x10b) [0x7f08a84977bb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x121) [0x7f08a8482535]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x3333443) [0x55b0b3460443]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x31dfac8) [0x55b0b330cac8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(recv_recovery_from_checkpoint_start(log_t&, unsigned long)+0x59a) [0x55b0b331668a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(srv_start(bool)+0x1880) [0x55b0b340fc60]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x2f8a086) [0x55b0b30b7086]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dd::bootstrap::DDSE_dict_init(THD*, dict_init_mode_t, unsigned int)+0x90) [0x55b0b2d72260]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dd::upgrade_57::do_pre_checks_and_initialize_dd(THD*)+0x18b) [0x55b0b2fbbf8b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x1fc8688) [0x55b0b20f5688]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x33a883c) [0x55b0b34d583c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7fa3) [0x7f08a8d79fa3]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x3f) [0x7f08a85594cf]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): Connection ID (thread ID): 1
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

How can I get the docker file running?
Thank you for your help!